# Umbraco 6.1.6 Ajax.BeginForm returns success but controller is never hits

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

Hello StackOverflowers

I followed this tutorial: [Ajax Umbraco MVC forms Guide](http://www.systenics.com/blog/creating-an-ajax-enabled-contact-form-in-umbraco-6-with-aspnet-mvc-4-and-twitter-bootstrap/?tag=Umbraco%206)

My code works before the ajax implementation.

After the small modifications, Ajax returns a success response but the controller breakpoint is never hits and so no email is ever sent

I am on 6.1.6 but the code is the same.  Any ideas?

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public class QuickContactController : SurfaceController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/mes-mini-contact.cshtml", new QuickContactModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MESQuickContactPost(Models.QuickContactModel model)
    {
        string smtp = "internalopenrelay.xxxxx.com";
        Document cSettings = new Document(1303);
        string from = cSettings.getProperty("fromAddress").Value.ToString();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //return CurrentUmbracoPage();
            return Json(new { sucess = false });
        }

        string _name = model.Name;
        string _email = model.Email;
        string _messsage = model.Message;

        SmtpClient SMTPClient = new SmtpClient(smtp);
        MailAddress FromAddress = new MailAddress(from);
        MailAddress ToAddress = new MailAddress("me@emailaddress.com");
        MailMessage Message = new MailMessage(FromAddress, ToAddress);
        Message.Body = string.Format("New message from: {0}<br>Email Address: {1}<p>{2}</p>", _name, _email, _messsage);
        Message.Subject = "New MES Quick Contact Message";
        Message.IsBodyHtml = true; ;
        try
        {
            SMTPClient.Send(Message);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        SMTPClient.Dispose();

        //return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class QuickContactModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model UmbracoUsStaging1.Models.QuickContactModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MESQuickContactPost", "QuickContactController", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "submit-status", OnFailure = "ShowError()", OnSuccess = "ShowSuccess()"}))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<span class="form-required">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</span><br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "flat-input width174", placeholder = "Name" })<br />    
<span class="form-required">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)</span><br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "flat-input width174", placeholder = "Email" })<br />
<span class="form-required">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)</span><br />
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "flat-input width174 height85", placeholder = "Message" })<br />
<br />
<a href="javascript:$('form').submit();" class="button-send">Send</a>
<div id="submit-status"></div>
<script>
    function ShowError() {
        $("#submit-status").html("Oops, there was an Error")
    }

    function ShowSuccess() {
        $("#submit-status").html("Message sent successfully");
        $("#Name").val("");
        $("#Email").val("");
        $("#Message").val("");
    }
</script>
}
```

My jQuery Refs:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have also tried with a regular Input type <input type="submit" value="Send" />

Comment: Well it seems i added the word Controller when calling Ajax.BeginForm when I should have left that part off.  Removed Controller from QuickContactController and its working!

Comment: Please repost your comment, but as an accepted solultion.